# Copy _id to new Field while creating new documents (save) using spring data mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data for mongoDB.

For my dummy object

```
{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String type;        
    private String objectType;  
    private String umbrellaId;  
}
```

In my object, the umbrellaId need to be the same as the generated Id. Now I have to do the following,

```
1. object = mongoRepo.save(object);
2. object.setumbrellaId(object.id);
3. object = mongoRepo.save(object);
```

Is it possible that it can be done with just one save() operation?

Comment: No, it is not possible. The generated Id  (ObjectId) is available to you after the document is saved to the collection - unless you are creating / generating the Id manually, before saving.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you can create an `ObjectId` when object is created

```
ObjectId id=new ObjectId()
```

If you need it to be `String`, then u can use `toString()` in the constructor.

```
String id;

yourclass(){
      ObjectId obj=new ObjectId();
      this.id=obj.toSting();
}
```

You can do this to all argument constructor also. Now you have the Id of `id` when object is created, so you can use it to `umbrellaId`;